# Find all called kernel API functions by a driver

Tags: debugging, window, kernel, reverse-engineering, hypervisor

Inspired by this problem that I asked in [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30980/how-find-all-kernel-functions-called-by-a-driver-in-windows-11), I tried to find out if there are some tools to monitor kernel drivers for some specific tasks. I am new both to hypervisors and reverse engineering so forgive my lack of knowledge.

I have a driver that hides all its imported functions and finds addresses that it needs by brute forcing memory so I need to find all those APIs by monitoring it. I am aware that you can do this task in user mode very easily with some tools, how ever in kernel mode I only find two candidate that seems capable of doing this job and still I am not sure if they can, one called [Hyperdbg](https://github.com/HyperDbg/HyperDbg) and the other [Didimon](https://github.com/tandasat/DdiMon) both work in hypervisor mode.

I even let windbg run targeted Driver for another 12 hours and still I was not able to trace a single kernel API call. So my main question is, How can I find all called kernel API functions by a driver within rational amount of time?

Comment: Edited to target main question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by hook them and register every call and ret address from the call if its equal to the driver you look for counting his calls

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).